# gsub replace text after set of characters

Tags: r, gsub

I have a lot of error messages that I am trying to clean up.

some of the errors end with the text `"(sec): 0.xxx"`
i'm trying to use gsub to remove everything after (sec)

```
data$Message <- gsub("(sec).*", "", data$Message, perl = TRUE)
```

this returns everything after (

I know it would be easy to just use ":" or ")" but then it effects other errors that I do not want to change.

Is there a way to use gsub to look at several characters -like "(sec)"- instead of just one? 
on a related note is their a symbol that represents any number (excludes text) similiar to "."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex *look behind* `?<=` to avoid `sec` being removed and at the same time assert the removed pattern follows `sec`, so `(?<=sec\\)).*` will remove everything after `sec)` but not `sec)` itself:

```
gsub("(?<=sec\\)).*", "", "(sec): 0.xxx", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "(sec)"
```

Comment: that worked! thank you. for others the exact code I used was. tarf$Message <- gsub("(?<=sec\\)).*", "", tarf$Message, perl = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first part of the expression (between brackets) and omit the rest:

```
gsub('(^.*\\(sec\\)).*', '\\1', '(sec): 0.xxx')

## [1] "(sec)"
```